# Updating a Dictionary with a Random Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I need to update the dict with a random key (the key is a nested dict) but when I do so, it gives me an error.

I have tried to use the .update, and used random.choice(dict), however this does nothing but give an error

```
dictA = { 1 : 2, 2 : 3, 3 : 4}
dictB = {}
dictB.update(random.choice(list(dictA)))
```

I expect dictB to have a random key, however, what I get is ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required.

Answer (score 4):

You can do a random choice on `dict.items()` which returns a random key - value pair from the dictionary:

```
k, v = random.choice(list(dictA.items()))
dictB.update({k: v})
```

Comment: this answer is more pythonic

Answer (score 0):

I am actually not sure about what you want to do, but assuming you want to update `dictB` with a random `item` (key, value of `dictA`):

```
item = random.choice(list(dictA.items()))
# item is a tuple (key, value)
dictB[item[0]] = item[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Break this down for proper debugging:

import random

```
dictA = { 1 : 2, 2 : 3, 3 : 4}
dictB = {}
listA = list(dictA)
pick = random.choice(listA)
print(listA, pick)
dictB.update(pick)
```

The output of the `print` is:

[1, 2, 3] 3

Thus, you're calling `update` with an argument of `3`, which isn't legal.  I *think* what you're trying to do is grab the whole entry, which you haven't done: rather, you made a list of the `dict` keys and made a random choice therefrom.

Try this at the end: construct a one-element dict of your chosen key and its value.

```
dictB.update({pick : dictA[pick]})
print(dictB)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3] 2
{2: 3}
```

Comment: I get an error: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are looking for

```
temp=random.choice(list(dictA))
dictB.update({temp:dictA[temp]})
```